# Is it pythonic to apply decorator to __init__ function?

Tags: python, python-decorators

Came across the need to do some sanity check of `__init__()` args. We'd like to move this sanity-checking logic into decorator.

I did some prototyping, it seems applying decorator to `__init__()` does work:

```
def my_dec(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print('a')
        func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

class testClass(object):
    @my_dec
    def __init__(self):
        print('b')
```

Having a decorator above `__init__` seems to be slightly messy. But besides that, is there any downside to this? Anything non-pythnoic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think "pythonic" here may be subjective (And I use may lightly) but I believe keeping to the more standard approach and doing sanity checks within `__init__` and keep the guessing to a minimum later on in debugging or when working with a team.

Something like this seems to do the same thing but feel more natural and is easier to follow.

```
def sanity_check():
    print('a')
    #do checks here
    return True #or False

class testClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        if sanity_check():
            print('b')
```

Comment: Definitely liking the 'keep guessing to minimum'. I did go with a function call. Because this check logic is really class specific, decided to use a @classmethod.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes:** one of Python's principles is to minimize clutter to improve readability, which is what wrappers do. `__init__` by design was intended to initialize passed parameters - which comes with its benefits:

- Easier to understand what parameters a given class will be working with, when reading code
- If said wrappers have important functionality (arg checks, etc), they *stand out* better and are *harder to miss* than if they were somewhere in the middle of `__init__`
- [Keras](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/optimizers.py#L412) uses two wrappers around a method that's similar to an init once understood, so it's not entirely uncommon

---

**No:** if `__init__` involves calling other methods for whatever reason, the wrapper(s) will apply to it also - which could be strongly undesirable. Stacking wrappers also requires careful design. These both go against the principle of *explicitness* in Python; it introduces additional untangling on behalf of the reader else avoided via class methods.

---

**Verdict**: Depends. In general, no. Sometimes, yes - can improve readability.

Comment: Thanks for the judgments! Giving it more thoughts, a decorator will require code reader a similar mental hop as a method call, given they are comfortable/familiar with decorators.

Comment: ....  given they are comfortable/familiar with decorators. Difference is decorator will points to a decorator definition, v.s. a plain method definition.
(kept hitting return.. )
For explicitness and readability, feel like the decorator-over-init is less preferable. And i'm probably giving this much more thoughts than its worth. And this check is only required when initializing the class object. Again, appreciate the mental exercise!